# Adding ImageIcon to JTabbedPane

Tags: java, jpanel, imageicon, jtabbedpane

I am attempting to add a picture to the first tab of a JTabbedPane, here is my code:

```
JTabbedPane application = new JTabbedApplication();
JPanel welcomePanel = new JPanel();
JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("track.jpg"));
welcomePanel.add(imageLabel);
application.addTab("WELCOME", welcomePanel);
application.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);
```

The image file is located in the same location as the class this code is in. For some reason, however, my image is not appearing. I have used the same JLabel and used text instead of an image and it appears. Can someone give me some insight into this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't know that the image is located directly beside the running class file. You have to hand in the absolute path. Which means Path + filename.

This little piece of code will help you to tell Java that the image is in the current working directory.

```
String file = new File("track.jpg").getAbsolutePath();
```

Added to your code snipped it looks like this:

```
JTabbedPane application = new JTabbedPane();
JPanel welcomePanel = new JPanel();
String file = new File("track.jpg").getAbsolutePath();

JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(file));
welcomePanel.add(imageLabel);
application.addTab("WELCOME", welcomePanel);
```

Comment: I tried that but the picture is still not appearing.

Comment: Why convert the `File` reference to `String` when `ImageIcon` can accept a `File` reference?  Besides, `ImageIO.read` would be generally more advisiable

Comment: At MadProgrammer: Well this was only because toAbsolutePath() returns a String. And as ImageIcon accepts both File and String. Why double-convert?

At Addison C: Sorry to hear that. Don't know why this does not work for you. When I tested it, it worked fine...

Answer (score 1):

> The image file is located in the same location as the class this code is in

Instead of `JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("track.jpg"));` which is looking for a file in the current working directory, you should be using `Class#getResource` which will return a `URL` to the embedded resource.

It's important to note, that resources which are store within the application context (ie embedded inside the Jar or within the source packages) aren't accessible as "files" anymore.

Instead, you could try using something like...

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("track.jpg"));
```

to load the image.  Unlike `ImageIcon`, `ImageIO.read` will throw an `IOException` if the image can't be read, which is always more useful than the silence that you get from `ImageIcon`

If this fails to work, more context on the structure of your app will be needed

Comment: I triied using that code @MadProgrammer but my  IDE stated upon compiling that getClass() could not be found. I tried: className.getClass(),  this.getClass(), className.getResource(), this.getResource() but none of these were able to compile properly.

Comment: Soooo, it sounds like you're trying to load the image from a `static` context ... gotta love `static`, you could use `application.getClass()`, but this assumes that the `JTabbedApplication` class is in the same package as the image.  If they are not, you could use an absolute path from the top package to your image instead